# Only Format <code> Tags w/ pygments

Tags: python, flask, markdown, pygments

I'm trying to use Pygments/Markdown to enable users to leave formatted code blocks in a project I'm working on using Flask. The problem I am having is that Pygments is formatting everything.

I would like to call Markdown on the text so that the `<code>` tags are added to the text and then have have Pygments only format the text in the `<code>` tags. Here is what I have tried.

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    entries = get_all_entries()
    lexer = PythonLexer()
    lexer.add_filter('codetagify')
    formatter = HtmlFormatter()
    for entry in entries:
        entry['text'] = markdown.markdown(entry['text'])
        entry['text'] = highlight(entry['text'], lexer, formatter)
    return render_template('list_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Where `entries` is a list of dictionaries and `entry['text']` is the body of the post. What happens in this configuration is that Pygments displays all the html formatted instead of allowing the browser to render it. I thought adding the `codetagify` filter would stop that form occurring. Any ideas on what I need to do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the answer myself. I only needed Pygments since Markdown uses it itself to color the code. I only need to include an extension in my `markdown.markdown()` call.

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    entries = get_all_entries()
    for entry in entries:
        entry['text'] = markdown.markdown(entry['text'], extensions=['codehilite'])
    return render_template('list_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

The `extensions=['codehilite']` parameter was all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think codetagify does what you think.  See http://pygments.org/docs/filters/

I don't know.  Maybe you have to separate out by yourself the parts of the text that you want formatted, and only pass those parts into the highlighter.  I think when they say "filter" they just mean something that converts text in some way.  It would be good if Pygments only formatted the parts of the text between code tags. Maybe there's a way to do that, but I didn't see it when glancing over the section titles of the documentation.

Comment: Yes and no. The pygments filter gives you the token stream, so you could write your own filter that ignores all tokens until it finds <code>, then render all tokens from that point until it finds </code>.